# how to access website inside docker container in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

All,

I deployed one master container in AWS. It contains a "Hello World" website. port 8080 is exposed and the AWS security group is set to accept inbound traffic from my workstation. Is there any way to enter a url in my browser and get to the website? I tried the public and private DNS and IP addresses but no luck

Comment: You mean deployed container on EC2 (or) using AWS ECS?

Comment: Its a docker container on EC2

Comment: What was the message you are getting when you tried to access with publicIP?'  Did you follow these steps? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

Comment: The message I'm getting is Unable to connect. Firefox, and Can't reach this page Edge.  I tried public DNS and public IP but still no luck

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The Containers are deployed from Docker Cloud, using Docker Swarm. I can see the instance in AWS running but I cannot open the website.

Comment: Ok, did you follow the proper port biding steps (like specified in my previous comment link) before running the container? It seems that is the step you are missing.

Comment: I would assume that you're not mapping the container port to the EC2 host port. 8080 is only opened inside the container. To link them, specify -p when you run the container. i.e. 8080:8080 will map port 8080 to the container's port 8080.